# How to show the number keyboard in edittext box in android?

Tags: android

I want to write only integer types in EditText but when I click on EditText it opens the Normal keyboard, but I only need a keyboard with numbers while I am doing this (all in Dialog box).

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `edittext` xml

```
android:inputType="number"
```

For more info see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

**EDIT:**
for programmatically setting this

```
yourEdittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: i am doing this in dialog box and creating edit text dynamically